# To set the alignment of a gauge highchart into a div tag of HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I want to set the alignment of an element which is rendered into a Div tag of HTML.I have written my code using jquery to make a multi gauge highchart in which i have divided my div tag into 6 parts and m rendering my each  gauge highchart into one of the part of div tag but the alignment of the gauge inside a div tag is not proper not coming in center.Visit the URL to see my working code.

Visit http://jsfiddle.net/8c7w84ac/3/

here's my html and css part code..

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highcharts Example</title>
         <style type="text/css">

#main{width:324px; height:205px; border:1px solid #ccc;}
#main div{ float:left; width:105px; height:100px; border:1px solid #ccc;.centered-axis-xy ;}

.actions, .chart {
        margin: 15px auto;
        width: 820px;
    }
    button {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E3E3E3;
        border: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
        border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #F6F6F6 inset;
        color: #333333;
        font: bold 12px;
        margin: 0 5px;
        padding: 8px 0 9px;
        text-align: center;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFFFFF;
        width: 150px;
    }
    button:hover {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #D9D9D9;
        box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #EAEAEA inset;
        color: #222222;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    button:active {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #D0D0D0;
        box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #E3E3E3 inset;
        color: #000000;
    }


         </style>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <script src="../../js/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="../../js/highcharts-more.js"></script>
    <script src="../../js/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <!-- Chart type switchers -->
<!--<div class="actions">
    <button class="switcher" id="column">column</button>
    <button class="switcher" id="area">area</button>
    <button class="switcher" id="line">line</button>
    <button class="switcher" id="spline">Spine</button>
    <button class="switcher" id="areaspline">areaspline</button>
    <button class="switcher" id="pie">pie</button>
</div>-->
<div class="actions">
<select id='media' name='media'>
    <option value="line">line</option>
    <option value="bar">bar</option>
    <option value="pie">pie</option>
    <option value="sparkLine">sparkLine</option>
    <option value="gauge">gauge</option>
    <option value="area">area</option>
</select>

</div>


    <!-- two different charts -->
    <!--<div id="chart_1" class="chart" style="height:100px;width:200px;"></div>
    <div id="chart_2" class="chart" style="height:100px;width:200px;"></div>-->

    <div id="main">
     <div id="chart_1" align="center">1</div>
     <div id="chart_2" align="center">2</div>
     <div id="chart_3" align="center">3</div>
     <div id="chart_4" align="center">4</div>
     <div id="chart_5" align="center">5</div>
     <div id="chart_6" align="center">6</div>
 </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

please check the alignment of each n every gauge.it should be placed in center.help me out please.All the 6 gauges should be equally aligned.

Comment: You have set `105px x 100px` to `#main div` and using `120px x 120px` for the guage in js options.

Comment: sorry i did'nt get you.where i need to place these values ??For which property i need to set the value to these values..??

Comment: If u check the js the code for gauge has width and height set to 120. I guess function go() go1() etc while in CSS you have #main div with width 105px

Comment: Fixed demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8c7w84ac/4/ (commented out width+height in options for the gauges).

Comment: ok..thank u..:)..it's working